# Git push stopped at total

Tags: git, github

While push my project on git hub the cmd stop at total, like the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSn2h.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can retry:

1. Is the content you push is big
2. The Internet connection got a problem
3. Try to add some local commit and try to push again

Comment: the problem was with internet connection , thank you